# Perf Profiler Reporting Excess Use of "do_syscall_64"

Tags: c, kernel, packet, perf, sendto

I'm attempting to optimize a program I wrote which aims to replicate network flows by sending packets to a specified MAC address.

The main loop of my program that is responsible for the sending and removal of flows is as follows:

```
while (size != 0 || response) {
    for (i = 0; size != 0 && i < size; ++i) {
       curFlow = *pCurFlow;
       while (curFlow.cur_time < now) {
           // Sending Packet
           sendto(sockfd, curFlow.buff, curFlow.length, 0, \
                 memAddr, sAddrSize);

           // Adjusting Packet Attributes
           curFlow.packets_left -= 1;
           curFlow.cur_time += curFlow.d_time;

           // If the packet has no packets left, delete it
           if (!curFlow.packets_left) {
                pCurFlow -> last -> next = pCurFlow -> next;
                pCurFlow -> next -> last = pCurFlow -> last;
                size -= 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        *pCurFlow = curFlow;
        pCurFlow = pCurFlow -> next;
    }
}
```

I've begun using the perf profiler to record what sort of function calls I'm making and how expensive each overhead is. However, every time I ask perf to give me a report, the outcome looks like:

```
Overhead  Command    Shared Object  Symbol
15.34%   packetize   /proc/kcore    0x7fff9c805b73   k [k] do_syscall_64
6.19%    packetize   /proc/kcore    0x7fff9d20214f   k [k] syscall_return_via_sysret
5.98%    packetize   /proc/kcore    0x7fff9d1a3de6   k [k] _raw_spin_lock      
5.29%    packetize   /proc/kcore    0x7fffc0512e9f   k [k] mlx4_en_xmit
5.26%    packetize   /proc/kcore    0x7fff9d16784d   k [k] packet_sendmsg
```

(Note: "packetize" is the name of my program)

My question is, what the heck is "do_syscall_64"?? After conducting some research, it seems like this particular function is a kernel tool used as an interrupt request.

Furthermore, I've found that the directory /proc/kcore is responsible for some components of memory management, although upon purposefully ransacking my program with memory references, the dynamic library I use with my program was the only overhead that increased from perf report.

Please let me know if you have any advice for me. Thank you!

Comment: syscall is short for system call, i.e. a call to a system/kernel function.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! That makes sense... do you have any advice on how to find the particular system call I am making in order to reduce its overhead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an interrupt request; it's the C function called from the `syscall` entry point that dispatches to the appropriate C function that implements the system call selected by a register passed by user-space.

Presumably `sys_sendto` in this case.

In older versions of Linux, the x86-64 `syscall` entry point used the system-call table of function pointers directly (e.g. as shown in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code) where only the 32-bit entry points like for `int 0x80` used a C wrapper function).

But with the changes for Spectre and Meltdown mitigation, the native 64-bit system call entry point (into a 64-bit kernel from 64-bit user-space) also uses a C wrapper around system call dispatching.  This allows using C macros and gcc hints to control speculation barriers before the indirect branch.  The current Linux version of [`do_syscall_64` on github](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/451577f3e3a9bf1861218641dbbf98e214e77851/arch/x86/entry/common.c#L278) is a pretty simple function; it's somewhat surprising it's getting so many cycles itself unless `nr = array_index_nospec(nr, NR_syscalls);` is a lot more expensive than I'd expect on your CPU.

There's definitely expensive stuff that happens in the hand-written-asm syscall entry point, e.g. writing the MSR that flushes the branch-prediction cache.  Oh, maybe lack of good branch prediction is costing extra cycles in the first C function called after that.

System-call intensive workloads suffer a lot from Spectre / Meltdown mitigations.  It might be interesting to try booting with some of them disabled, and/or with an older kernel that doesn't have that code at all.

Meltdown / L1TF / etc. are completely fixed in the newest Intel CPUs with no performance cost, so disabling workarounds for that might give you some clue how much benefit you'd get from a brand new CPU.

(Spectre is still a very hard problem and can't be easily fixed with a local change to the load ports.  IDK what the details are of how efficient various mitigation microcode-assisted or not strategies for mitigating it are on various CPUs.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the informative answer! This is exactly what I needed, and perhaps you're correct about branch prediction as I am currently at a 2% misprediction (which with the number of times this loop runs is actually 95 million misses for a 10 Gb/s flow, yikes!). I was wondering if you had any suggestions on a profiler that could be used to find what sort of kernel calls are being utilized, although sys_sendto is an intelligent guess.

Comment: @NolanRudolph: you can use `strace` to log what system calls your code makes.  Or probably you get some hits further down in the profile for the actual system-call implementations.  There might be tracepoints or whatever that let you get `perf` itself to record which system calls are being invoked, IDK.  I usually tune / SIMD optimize computationally intensive code that makes only a few system calls for I/O so it's not something I know a lot about digging into.

Comment: That's quite alright, and I'll definitely make sure to look into strace! I appreciate all the help, you've aided my project greatly :)